# Mosquitto MQTT service failed to restart after adding SSL configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to configure SSL access to my mosquitto bridrge on Amazon EC2, Ubuntu 18 server. I followed the steps described in [mosquitto tls docs](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-tls-7.html) and ended up with the following files:

1. ca.crt
2. ca.key
3. ca.srl
4. client.crt
5. client.csr
6. client.key
7. server.crt
8. server.csr
9. server.key

in a temporary directory.

Then I copied three files:

```
sudo cp ca.crt /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/
sudo cp server.key /etc/mosquitto/certs/
sudo cp server.crt /etc/mosquitto/certs/
```

Then I added the following section to the configuration file:

```
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
```

Then I wanted to restart mosquitto:

```
sudo service mosquitto restart
```

This doesn't work and responds with

```
> Job for mosquitto.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
> See "systemctl status mosquitto.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I tried both and there was just information, that the configuration is wrong.

I tried commenting out different lines and the following structure let's the service restart:

```
listener 8883
cafile /etc/mosquitto/ca_certificates/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
#certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
```

Unfortunatelly, the certfile is nessesary for the configuration to work. I checked the example configuration and the docs, and the certfile is a legal and required parameter.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: were you able to do this on ec2 ? I am stuck as well , same errorafter adding path to certs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running **Mosquitto on Ubuntu** server. I ran also into  Mosquitto failing to start after adding SSL certificates and configuration. I got a **standalone** certificate from **Let’s Encrypt** by **Certbot** tool.

**Version information:**
Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS,
Mosquitto 2.0.4. (MQTT v5.0/v3.1.1/v3.1 broker) and
Certbot 1.11.0.

In original and failing configuration the mosquitto was configured to use certificates in /etc/letsencrypt... location.

My solution was to **move all certificate files from /etc/letsencrypt/archive/ into /etc/mosquitto/** -folder and make the **respective certificate file pointers in mosquitto configuration to point to this location**.

Most relevant debugging for the problem in the trouble shooting is available in the logfile /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log file.*

*Further info about troubleshooting*

Playing around with *ownerships did not have any effect*, in this case. The final configuration with certificates in /etc/mosquitto/certs folder worked regardless if the owner of the files and certificate containing folder was mosquitto or root.

I also tried not using the symbolic links of .../live/... and tested using directly the files in /etc/letsencrypt/archive/... location instead, did not work.

I did not check if some individual file is causing the issue, just moved them all. Tried afterwards to symlink from ..mosquitto/certs one of the files only to note that mosquitto will fail to start. For this server set-up to run, I need to **keep the certificate files in ...mosquitto/certs folder"**.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the certificate/key permissions fixed the issue for me.
E.g.

sudo chmod 744 raspberrypi.crt

sudo chmod 644 raspberrypi.key

As per this forum:-
https://github.com/owntracks/tools/issues/6

Comment: It is work on me. Thanks!!